# Seek him or Seeks him?

Tags: word-usage, difference

Is the following sentence correct:

> Others even seek him out for advice.

What is the proper word to use in the sentence, seek or seeks?

Comment: What rules do you know about using the "-s" form of verbs?  Why do you find those rules hard to apply in this case?

Comment: If there was only ***one*** other person, it would be singular *The other even **seeks** him out for advice*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, So if there was more than one person seeking him out, we use the word seeks, correct ? thanks for your effort to explain.

Comment: No - if there was more than one person seeking him out, we'd use the plural verb ***seek***, not singular ***seeks***. Note that *the **other*** refers to ***one*** person, so it goes with singular verb ***seeks***, whereas *the **others*** refers to ***two or more*** people, so the verb form is plural ***seek***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "others" indicates multiple people, so it calls for **seek**. You can replace it with **they**:

> **They** even **seek** him out for advice.

If only one person was seeking him out for advice, let's say this person's name is Sarah, then you would use **seeks**:

> **Sarah** even **seeks** him out for advice.

You could replace it with she (or he):

> **She** even **seeks** him out for advice.

The sentence you wrote originally is correct.

See also [how to conjugate the verb "to seek"](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-seek.html).

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer.